# How to select li in div with situation?

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

Could the CSS masters suggest using which instruction possible to select a certain element number "li" in the situation below? For example, how to highlight yellow the first "li" one using nth-child or another instruction?

```css
.layer li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 7px 13px 12px 10px;
    }
    .layer li {
        counter-reset: item;
    }
    .layer li:before {

        width: 26px;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        content: counter(item) " ";
        counter-increment: item;
        font-size: 14pt;
        padding: 1px;
        background-color: black;
        color: darkorange;
        background-size: 8px 8px;
        border-radius: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin: 0px 4px -2px 0px;
    }
    


.container .layer:nth-of-type(2) ul li {

        background-color: yellow !important;
 }
 
 p {
white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="">

        <div class="layer"><ul><li><p>First</p></li></ul></div>
    
    
    
        <div class="layer"><ul><li>2</li></ul></div>
        <div class="layer"><ul><li>3</li></ul></div>
        <div class="layer"><ul><li>4</li></ul></div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: A `li` elements parent needs to be a `ol` or `ul`, not a `div`, not a `p`. This is invalid HTML.

Comment: also `nth-child(1)` selects all the first child elements of the class layer. It is true for all your `li` elements. to only select the first `li` element they all need the same parent or you need to use just `.container li:nth-of-type(1)` selector.

Comment: Thank you for your attention to my problem, I have slightly redone the code and I am satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML seems a bit redundant. Also the counter reset is not proper. Did you want to achieve this?

```css
.layer {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding:0;
}

.layer li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.layer li:before {
  width: 1.2em;
  aspect-ratio:1;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  counter-increment: item;
  content: counter(item);
  font-size: 14pt;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: black;
  color: darkorange;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: .5em;
}

.container .layer li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="">
  <ol class="layer">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank for a solution, could someone suggest how to prohibit line wrapping to the next one in the case of the "p" tag in my variant?

Answer (score 0):

Note: that `li` element needs to be inside an `ol` or an `ul` tag, and not inside a `div` or a `p` tag.

```
<ul>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>

 </ul>
```